# Is there any efficient pdf library in react which gets the base64 content from API and displays the output in the form of pdf?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-pdf

I am using a library in React called **react-pdf** which is having a component `Document. Document` Component contains a property called *file* (whose input type is a string).
How can I pass my response(props from redux) which is a base64 content, from the API into *file* property of *Document*?. So, Is there any library that accepts my base64 content from API and displays the output in a pdf document?

Here is the sample code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Document } from 'react-pdf';

import { pdfData } from '../Store/ActionCreators'

class Billing extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.pdfData(mobile);
  }

  render() {
    const { base64 } = this.props;
    return (
      <Document file=''>

      </Document>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  base64: state.login.data
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { pdfData })(Billing);
```

If I pass base64 to *file* then it is considering it as a string and outputting as *base64*.

Is there any relevant solution to work it out effectively?

Answer (score 0):

Pdf-lib does support base64 by default and attached a sample to show how, and you need to know the pages numbers for your base64 document and to do that I used [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) that I pass the base64 and get the attributes will be used to manipulate base64 document "rotating-scaling-merging-pdf-addImage-etc"

[Sandbox Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-sinoussi-gm91j?file=/src/styles.css)

```
const pdfDocument = await PDFDocument.load(base64);
const numPages = pdfDocument.getPageIndices();
```

Then pass the props and your data to as follow:

```
<Document file={`data:application/pdf;base64,${base64}`}>

             {numPages.map((page, ind) => {
              return <div key={ind} id={`viewer-page-${ind+1}`} className=" some-class-names">
                <Page
                  key={`page_${ind + 1}`}
                  pageNumber={ind + 1}
                  scale={1} // you can scale by updating this
                  rotate={0} // you can scale by updating this 
                  className={'some-class-names-page'}
                  width={400}
                  renderAnnotationLayer={false} // true by default
                  onRenderSuccess={renderMetricTracker}
                />
              </div>;
            })}
</Document>
```